# Conditional undeploy on glassfish

Tags: deployment, glassfish, glassfish-3, asadmin

I'm learning Jenkins these days and I faced a situation. I need to execute conditional `undeploy` on glassfish. I want to undeploy an application only if it exsits in the server. Is there a way to do this in a single command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do so, I used the followin Bash code:

```
apps=`asadmin list-applications -t --user=admin --passwordfile=password.txt`

for app in $apps
do
    if [ $app = "the_name_of_your_app" ]
    then
        asadmin --user=admin --passwordfile=password.txt undeploy the_name_of_your_app
    fi
done;
```

PS: the content of password.txt is a single line: `AS_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin`

I hope it will help someone someday  =)